# Android mediastore not returning all internal storage images in phone. It is only showing images lockscreen and wallpaper images. Any solution?

Tags: android, local-storage, storage, android-gallery, mediastore

Please give me a solution for loading all images from internal and external storage of android phone?
My method below returns only wallpapers and lockscreen images. For testing, I'm using mi redmi note 3 with android v6.0 os and No External storage inserted.
Please give me the latest solution. I'm a beginner to android.

```
public ArrayList<String> getImagePaths() {
            ArrayList<String> resultIAV = new ArrayList<String>();
            URI u = MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(u, projection, null,
                    null, null);

            column_index_data = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);

            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                absolutePathOfImage = c.getString(column_index_data);
                resultIAV.add(absolutePathOfImage);
            }

            return resultIAV;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to get all images from internal and External storage and do not forget to add
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
 permission in your manifest file.

```
int dataColumnIndex;
int bucketColumnIndex;
int displayNameColumnIndex;
String GalleryThumbnail_Path;
String bucket;
String displayName;
int imageCounter = 0;

Thread getImages = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME
        };
        String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        try {
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, columns, null, null, orderBy);
            assert cursor != null;
            int mCount = cursor.getCount();
            for (int i = mCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (imageCounter <= 370) {
                    cursor.moveToPosition(i);
                    dataColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                    bucketColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
                    displayNameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                    GalleryThumbnail_Path = cursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
                    bucket = cursor.getString(bucketColumnIndex);
                    displayName = cursor.getString(displayNameColumnIndex);
                    myimagesPath.add(GalleryThumbnail_Path);
                    myStorage.add(bucket + "-->" + displayName);
                    imageCounter++;
                    Log.e("Recents " + i + "-->>", "Added to bucket");
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This works in Android 7.1.2 also (My OnePlus One-which i use for development)

Comment: Thanks for your help. it works. I thought EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI is for showing sd card images only. I was using INERNAL_CONTENT_URI for internal images.Now i get External + Internal images.